# ASP.NET MVC 4, EF, & LINQ: Creating a specific LINQ query for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application, I am trying to write a ListStudents ActionResult that will only display a list of students whose **ClassroomID** is equal one of the ClassroomID's that the currently logged on teacher has created.

I believe that I need to use a few LINQ queries to get the desired result but I am stuck because I do not quite know how to handle it when the teacher entity has an ICollection of classrooms.

**ListStudents & CreateClassroom in my TeacherController**

```
public ActionResult ListStudents()
{
        //This gets the current teachers UserProfile as only users with the teacher role have access to this controller

        var teacherProfile = db.UserProfiles.Local.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
            ?? db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

        var teacher = db.Teachers.Find(teacherProfile.UserId);

        //Need query where students ClassroomID needs to be one of the current teachers ClassroomID's

        return View(students);
}

public ActionResult CreateClassroom(Classroom model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var userProfile = db.UserProfiles.Local.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                    ?? db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

                var classroom = new Classroom
                {
                    ClassroomName = model.ClassroomName,
                    TeacherID = userProfile.UserId

                };
                db.Classrooms.Add(classroom);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DataException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong, try again.");
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ListClassrooms");
    }
```

**Models For User, Student, Teacher, and Classroom**

```
    public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Editable(false)]
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required.")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Student**

```
    public class Student : User
{
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    [Editable(false)]
    public virtual int AccountID { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    [Column("ClassroomID")]
    [ForeignKey("Classroom")]
    public virtual int ClassroomID { get; set; }

    public virtual Classroom Classroom { get; set; }
}
```

**Teacher**

```
    public class Teacher : User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
}
```

**Classroom**

```
    public class Classroom
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int ClassroomID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Classroom Name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string ClassroomName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    [Column("TeacherID")]
    [ForeignKey("Teacher")]
    public virtual int TeacherID { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for your time to help me solve this, I am very new to MVC and am trying to learn as much as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broken out into a couple lines which makes it easier to understand.

```
var classrooms = db.Classrooms.Where(x => x.TeacherID == teacher.Id).Select(x => x.ClassroomID);
var students = db.Students.Where(x => classrooms.Contains(x.ClassroomID);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly! I am having a little trouble understanding what the first query is doing. If you don't mind, could you kind of walk me through exactly what it is doing?

Comment: The first thing you need for this query is a collection of classrooms.  Once you have those classrooms you can see what students belong to those classrooms.  In the first query, I'm getting a collection of Classrooms using the WHERE clause.  From that collection, I only really care about the Ids (which is where the SELECT clause comes into play).  The classrooms variable is actually just a collection of integers.